# How to extract title from html body saved in mongodb, using server side javascript execution?

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb collection, documents with html body and 
i want to extract text of `html>head>title` tag from each document.
I'm currently doing this with python and its causing too much network traffic.
I have read in mongodb on can execute server side javascript and i tried
`mongo test.js`  with the following code

```
var db = connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/analytics');
var body = db.https.find({},{_id:0,"data.body": 1}).limit(40);
while (body.hasNext()) {
    var resp =  body.next()
    var htmlBody=resp.body
    var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = htmlBody
    var title = el.getElementsByTagName( 'title' );
    print(title)
}
```

`E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: ReferenceError: document is not defined :`
Is this possible server side if so how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB server side javascript does not include a HTML parsing or DOM library.

The `data.body` field probably contains a string.  If you control the data ingest, you will probably find it simpler to parse the HTML on the way in, and store the title in a different field.

The only option I can thing of server-side is a regex, but that is usually [not an easy think to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2282634)